# Continuity of the constant in maximal Sobolev regularity

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, regularity, interpolation-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a smooth, bounded domain. For each pair $(p, q) \in (1, \infty)^2$, maximal regularity asserts that there is some $\widetilde K(p, q) > 0$ such for all $f \in L^q((0, \infty); L^p(\Omega))$ the solution $u$ of
$$\begin{cases}
  u_t = \Delta u - u + f& \text{in }\Omega \times (0, \infty), \\
  \partial_\nu u = 0 & \text{on }\partial \Omega \times (0, \infty), \\
  u(\cdot, 0) = 0 & \text{in }\Omega
\end{cases}$$
fulfils
$$\|u_t\|_{L^q((0, \infty); L^p(\Omega))} + \|(-\Delta + 1) u\|_{L^q((0, \infty); L^p(\Omega))} \leq \widetilde K(p, q) \|f\|_{L^q((0, \infty); L^p(\Omega))}.$$

Let $K(p, q)$ be the infimum of all $\widetilde K(p , q)$. **Question:** Is $K \colon (1, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ continuous?

By complex interpolation, one quickly obtains that $1/p \mapsto K(p, p)$ is log-convex and hence continuous. Thus I am curious whether $K$ is also continuous in $(p, q)$. Does this perhaps follow by some abstract interpolation theory which then would, for instance, also assert continuity of the constant in the Gagliardo--Nirenberg inequality?

Comment: Maybe I am dense here but why does the log-convex argument via complex interpolation not equally well apply to $(1/p,1/q) \mapsto K(p,q)$?

Comment: @Hannes: Thanks! Indeed, that works with the same proof. For some reason I thought one only gets continuity along straight lines, but one obtains first convexity (which is only concerned with behaviour on straight lines) on $(0, 1)^2$ and then concludes continuity on $(0, 1)^2$.